# Assigning a value to integer pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, identifier

I have some troubles regarding some variations of code.

```
int *p = 5;
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

Output : `SEGMENTATION FAULT`

```
int *p = 5;
printf("%d\n", p);
```

Output: `5`

What is happening here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cant assign an _integer_ to a _integer pointer_.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One moment it crashes and burns, the next it seemingly works, and the next again it overwrites your computers bootblock.

Comment: @Tezuesh Varshney  Where is the constant integer pointer?

Comment: In the first case `p` has the address `5`. It now points to that memory location. With `*p` in the `printf()` you are trying to get the value in memory location `5` which is probably not part of the memory that the program is allowed to access.

Comment: With that out of the way, what's *really* happening is that in the first example, you make `p` point to the location `5`. You then dereference that location to get the `int` value stored there. Since `5` is hardly a valid location in most programs, especially for an `int`, the operating system detects it and ends your process with a segmentation fault.

Comment: `int *p=5;` is same as `int *p; p=5;`. Not `int *p; *p=5;`

Comment: The second programs seems to work because you don't actually use the contents in location `5`, you use the contents of the *variable* `p` (which is equal to `5`). This also have undefined behavior since you're using the wrong format specifier to print the pointer. The `"%d"` format is to print `int` *values*, not *pointers to `int`*. To print a `void *` (i.e. a generic pointer) you must first cast the pointer, then use the `"%p"` format specifier.

Comment: `int *p = 5;` is not legal C. You should have received [a warning or an error](https://ideone.com/FT7JAI) from the compiler. If you haven't, get a different compiler. If you have, please make sure you remember to refrain from posting questions about programs that produce warnings, **unless** you want to ask about the warnings themselves.

Comment: Lastly some nitpicking: There's no "constant integer pointer" anywhere.

Comment: Don't you get any warnings for the lack of a cast operator?

Comment: @DavidBowling the difference is of no interest for non-compiler-writers, unless they can justify using implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @n.m. no it is not legal, integer to pointer conversion is only allowed if it is explicit, that is if there is a cast.

Comment: @JensGustedt-- n.m. stated that `int *p = 5` is not legal; I am the one who claimed that it is legal. But you are right; it is not legal. I forgot about the requirement to use an explicit cast for conversions involving pointers. Deleting my previous comment.

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't see such requirement in the C standard. 6.3.2.3 seems to specify conversions that can be done *without* a cast, because there are definitely things not listed there that can be done *with* a cast.

Comment: @n.m. it is somewhat hidden. If you look closely it says that an integer *may* be converted to a pointer, but that there is no context where such a conversion is done implicitly. For the assigment operator the standard states which types are allowed on the RHS if the LHS is a pointer. Initialization just follows the rules for assignment. This restriction for assigment is a "shall" in the "Constraints" section, so it must be diagnosed.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes you are right, 6.5.4 says "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of
6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast". So it's not legal after all.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Note: This answer is only here to help the OP understand pointers a little better (I hope), it's not to actually answer the question itself.</sub>

Lets create a little *working* program that shows the difference between pointers and values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 5;    // Define a variable, initialize it with a value
    int *p = &i;  // Define a pointer, make it point to the location of the variable i

    printf("The value of i is %d\n", i);  // Should be pretty obvious

    // Dereference the pointer, fetching the value stored in the variable i
    // Will say the value of *p is 5, because *p is actually the variable i
    printf("The value of *p is %d\n", *p);

    // Print the address of i, the location of the variable in memory
    printf("The location of the variable i is %p\n", (void *) &i);

    // Print the address of i again, using the pointers value
    printf("The value of p is %p\n", (void *) p);  // Note: No dereferencing

    // Print the address of the variable p, i.e. where p is stored in memory
    printf("The location of the variable p is %p\n", (void *) &p);  // Note use of address-of operator &

    return 0;
}
```

The actual addresses (locations) of the variables, what the last three `printf` calls will actually print, will vary. The location of variables depends on the compiler and the operating system.

---

A little more "graphically" it can bee seen something like this:

```
+----------------------------------+
| the variable i, contents equal 5 | <--\
+----------------------------------+    |
| the variable p, contents depends | ---/
+----------------------------------+
```

From the "images" above, the variable `p` *points* to the variable `i`.

---

Now for the important part: A pointer *must* point to a valid location if you want to dereference it, i.e. if you want to get the contents of where it's pointing. If it doesn't then you will have *undefined behavior*.

However, just having a pointer initialized with any random value is in itself not a problem, as long as you don't try to dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is undefined in both cases:

- `int *p = 5;` defines a pointer to `int` initialized the a hard-coded value of `5`, most likely invalid. `printf("%d\n", *p);` dereferences this pointer, which has an invalid value, hence the segmentation fault.
- in the second example, `printf("%d\n", p);` the value of the pointer is printed, so you get `5`, but the conversion specifier `%d` is invalid for the value of a pointer, so the behavior is undefined and the output may be different on other systems.

`int *p = 5; printf("%d\n", (int)p);` solves this problem, but the implicit conversion from `int` to `int *` is still not guaranteed to succeed. This kind of code is only used for very specific environments, such as embedded systems or operating systems. Raising the compiler warning level lets the compiler issue warnings or even errors for this (`gcc -Wall` or `clang -Weverything`...)

The C11 Standard says:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

If it is a trap representation, just passing the pointer to `printf` has undefined behavior.

Furthermore, such conversions, except for the value `0`, should be explicit by means of a cast.

Comment: @DavidBowling: That's an interesting question. Definitely dereferencing the pointer may have undefined behavior.  The C11 Standard says: **6.3.2.3 Pointers** *An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.* If it is a trap representation, just passing the pointer to `printf` has undefined behavior.  I don't know if this could be considered a *successful* conversion ;-)

Comment: I had already deleted my comment when I saw your response. Jens Gustedt had pointed out in the comments under the OP that `int *p = 5` is not legal since it violates the constraints for simple assignment in §6.5.16.1/1. Also, §6.5.4/3 says that "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast." So as written, there is a constraint violation. With the cast, the value held by `p` seems mostly meaningless, so maybe "successful conversion" would be an overstatement ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting p value to 5.
*p  will look for some thing stored in address 5, which will lead to segmentation fault.
p should point to a valid memory address.

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
printf("%d\n",*p ); //will print 5
printf("%p\n", p); //will print address of a -> &a
```